# CMS for static website

Tags: html, editor, admin

hey guys I was wondering how you would create a backend admin system in order to edit page content. For example, to change the information on the **contact us** or **about us** page without having to go in the coding bit. I understand cms from the database side but cannot see how to edit static content without database.

Comment: IMHO just install WordPress, Joomla or Drupal and forget this kind of trickery. You could do it by reading the files with php, showing content in editor like TinyMce and saving the results.. but i suggest not to do that.

Comment: Most [staticsitegenerator](https://staticsitegenerators.net/) store their data source in plain files, written in a lightwight markup (e.g markdown). So you wont need to code any thing if you want to change content pages.